# Remove symbols from list (Scheme)?

Tags: list, scheme, symbols

I'm fairly new to scheme and have been playing around with it and one of the problems I have placed upon myself is to remove all symbols from a single list of elements.

```
    (define lst '(a 2 3 a 2 d 3))

    (define removeSymbol
      (lambda (lst)
            (if (null? lst)
             '()
             (if (symbol? (car lst))
                 (removeSymbol (cdr lst))
                 (cons car lst) (removeSymbol (cdr lst))))))

    (removeSymbol lst)
```

I feel like this should work, but it is not giving me what I am expecting.
My expectation: (list 2 3 2 3)

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned your unmet expectation, but not your result.

I'm guessing you're seeing a syntax error (in Racket, I get: `if: bad syntax; has 4 parts after keyword`) because the body of your nested `if` contains 3 s-expressions.

```
  (if (symbol? (car lst))
    (removeSymbol (cdr lst))
    (cons car lst) 
    (removeSymbol (cdr lst)))
```

If you shuffle your parens so that they look like the following, your function should work as expected:

```
(define lst '(a 2 3 a 2 d 3))

(define (removeSymbol lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (if (symbol? (car lst))
        (removeSymbol (cdr lst))
        (cons (car lst) (removeSymbol (cdr lst))))))

(removeSymbol lst) ;; '(2 3 2 3)
```

I appreciate you're just working through this example as a learning exercise, but what you're attempting to do could also be achieved (arguably) a bit more idiomatically using the prelude functions `filter`, `negate` and `symbol?`:

```
(filter (negate symbol?) lst) ;; '(2 3 2 3)
```

Comment: I have not come across filter in my learning yet. Thanks for the suggestion and the input! and yes, you were correct in identifying my result.